# Join equivalent with mongoose/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Most of my experience is with MySQL and I'm basically trying to do a join equivalent with Mongoose. I need to query all the users that have orders with a certain partner_id. This is how I would write the query in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM guestUsers
LEFT JOIN partnerOrders ON guestUsers.id = partnerOrders.guest_user_id
WHERE partnerOrders.partner_id = "TF"
```

In my partnerOrders schema I have the guest_user_id field which is an objectId that references guestUsers

```
guest_user_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'guestUser' }
```

Here is what I have so far with mongoose, but I may be approaching this completely wrong because of my lack of experience

```
const guest_users = await guestUserModel.aggregate( [
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'partnerOrders', 
    localField: '_id', 
    foreignField: 'guest_user_id', 
    as: 'partnerOrders',
    let: {partner_id: "$partner_id"},
    pipeline: [
      {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$partner_id",  "TF"] }}}
    ]
  }
}
])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot` can help to seperate the array members (result of lookup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- lookup with pipeline to match the "TF" also
- unwind to seperate the array members
- merge with root and replace it
- project the lookup field (information moved on root anyways)

*i couldn't test it on your sample data but i think with this you will be able to do it, else if you can add sample data and expected output.

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=622cc6546f902a4b4b2e75f4)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
   {"from": "partnerOrders",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "guest_user_id",
    "pipeline": [{"$match": {"partner_id": {"$eq": "TF"}}}],
    "as": "partnerOrders"}},
 {"$unwind": 
   {"path": "$partnerOrders", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}},
 {"$replaceRoot": 
   {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$partnerOrders", "$$ROOT"]}}},
 {"$unset": ["partnerOrders"]}])
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time but unfortunately my request got lost in translation. Perhaps it's because I'm approaching it wrong with lookup. I'm looking to query all the customers that have orders with the partner_id. I'm not looking to query any of the orders rather I need to filter the list of customers based on if they have an order with the partner_id

Comment: I could query all the unique customer ids directly from partnerOrders then populate the user model. Do you think there's a better solution?

Comment: Never mind  this is a dumb question I should just store the partner_id(s) in an array under the customer.

Comment: i updated the answer i added the option `"preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true` to keep the guestUsers even if they didnt join with any `partnerOrder` because you had left-join. if it doesnt do what you need, if you can add sample data and expected output.